# Sanguinololu 1.3a fan connection

Tags: cooling, fans

Can anyone tell me where to connect a cooling fan on the Sanguinololu v1.3a board?  A few of the information pages mention three PWM outputs: Extruder, bed heater and fan, but none of the wiring diagrams that I can find, actually show the connections for the fan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that there isn't an "out-of-the-box" solution to your request, but luck is with you. Someone with your board and objective has posted what appears to be a reasonable modification:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Add-a-Cooling-Fan-to-your-Rep-Rap-Sanguinololu/

Comment: Yes, this confirms what I was beginning to think and it is a mod I can handle. Thanks.